# Did Abraham have faith in the future coming of Christ?

Tags: soteriology, abraham

R.C. Sproul's book on Romans, Chapter 10, page 106.

> "When Paul speaks of Abraham's justification as being by faith, that is shorthand for saying that Abraham was justified by the righteousness of Christ.  The only difference between our justification and Abraham's is that Abraham looked forward to the promised one."

Is there biblical evidence that Abraham looked forward to Christ.  I know that it's felt that a view of Christ in the future is given in Genesis 3:

> "And I will put enmity between you and the woman, And between your seed and her seed; He shall bruise you on the head, and you shall bruise Him on the heel.”

However it is believed that this was written by Moses, long after Abraham.  Assuming that Genesis was written by Moses, was it from oral tradition that Abraham would have known, or was it direct revelation from God to Moses?  Is there some other way we can assume that Abraham and other patriarchs had knowledge of the coming of Christ?

Comment: Are you asking about how they knew that a Messiah was coming?  This question appears to mix up multiple points.

Comment: Kovin - Essentially yes, although not just how did they know a Messiah was coming, but is there anything in the Bible that indicates that they knew.

Comment: Christ himself taught that Abraham "rejoiced at seeing my day"...

Comment: Andrew - Thanks.  Sadly, I hadn't looked in the NT for my answer.

Comment: According to Jesus, yes: John 8:56.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also find in the account of Abraham and Isaac at Mt Moriah that Abraham told Isaac that God Himself would provide a "Lamb" when Isaac asked about the burnt offering.

By this we know Abraham was speaking prophetically of a future time when God would offer up His Son/Lamb because, what was provided at that point in time was a "Ram" caught in the thicket by it's horns, not a Lamb as Abraham had stated. God's Word is amazing.

Comment: Good point.  I'll have to look at a concordance to check on Ram and Lamb.  But what you said makes sense to me.  Although it is kind of subtle.

Comment: Yes there are many "pictures" of Christ in the Old Testament as 1 Corinthians 10:4 gives us an example of. This is the beauty of the scriptures that sadly, many people miss. Luke 24:27 teaches us that Jesus "expounded" to 2 disciple's all the things concerning "HIMSELF"...

Answer (score 1):

> -OP-Is there biblical evidence that Abraham looked forward to Christ.[?]

The authors of Genesis, Hebrews, and Galatians spell out the promise of God.  This means the answer is yes.

> And God said, Sarah thy wife shall bear thee a son indeed; and thou shalt call his name Isaac: and I will establish my covenant with him for an everlasting covenant, and with his **seed** after him. Gen. 17:19
>
> Of whom it was said, That in Isaac shall thy **seed** be called: Heb. 11:17
>
> Now to Abraham and his seed were the promises made. He saith not, And to seeds, as of many; but as of one, And to thy **seed**, which is Christ. Gal. 3:16

And so, Abraham looked forward to Christ, to the promised seed.